# Split a string based on ASCII value

Tags: perl, ascii

I need to parse a delimited file.(generated by mainframe job and ftped over to windows).But got few **Q**ueries while using the split on delimiter.

As per the documentation, the file is separated by **'1D'**. But when I open the file in notepad++(*when I check the encoding tab, it is set to 'Encode in ANSI'*), it seems to me like a 'vertical broken bar'. **Q**. Not sure what is '1D'?

[image]

```
open my $handle, '<', 'sample.txt';
chomp(my @lines = <$handle>);
close $handle;
my @a = unpack("C*", $lines[0]);
print Dumper \@a;
# $VAR1 = [65,166,66,166,67,166];
```

From dumper output, we see perl considers the ASCII for vertical broken bar to be 166.

As per [link1](https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/), 166 is indeed vertical broken bar whereas as per [link2](https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/feminine-ordinal-indicator-ascii-code-166.html), 166 is feminine ordinal indicator.**Q.** Any suggestion as to why the difference ?

```
my $str = $lines[0];
print Dumper $str;
# $VAR1 = 'AªBªCª';
```

We can see that the output contains 'feminine ordinal indicator' not 'vertical broken bar'.**Q.** Not sure why perl reads a 'bar' but then starts treating it as something else.

```
# I copied the vertical broken bar from notepad++ for use below
my @b = split(/¦/, $lines[0]);
print Dumper \@b;
# $VAR1 = [ 'AªBªCª' ];
```

Since perl has started treating bar to be something else, as expected, no split here.I thought to split by giving the ascii code of 166 directly. Seems split() doesn't support ASCII as an argument. **Q**. Any workaround to pass ASCII code to split() ?

```
# I copied the vertical broken bar from notepad++ and created A¦B¦C
my @c = split(/¦/, 'A¦B¦C');
print Dumper \@c;
#$VAR1 = [ 'A','B','C']; # works as expected, added here just for completion
```

Any pointers will be a great help!

```
Update:
my @a = map {ord $_} split //, $lines[0]; print Dumper \@a;
# $VAR1 = [ 65,166,66,166,67,166];
```

Comment: What do you get from this `open my $handle, '<', 'sample.txt';
chomp(my @lines = <$handle>);
close $handle;
my @a = map {ord $_} split //, $lines[0];
print Dumper \@a;`

Comment: I'd recommend dumping the file with a tool like `xxd` or `hexdump` to verify that input isn't being converted by perl in some unexpected way (as `0x1D` is 29, GS (group separator), not 166). If so you might benefit from calling `binmode` on your file handle (or using a PerlIO layer like `:encoding(ascii)`) to ensure it is read raw.

Comment: ASCII only has 128 characters. There is no character 166 in ASCII. People talk about "[extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) character sets" but that's just a recipe for confusion because (as you've seen) there are many conflicting definitions of those next 128 characters. It looks like your first link goes to a definition of the Windows character set [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). I'm not sure which character encoding your second link is talking about.

Comment: The most important thing you can do is to ask the people supplying your file what character encoding it is using.

Comment: @JGNI : Added the output as an update to question

Comment: Strings passed by the command line have the OS encoding. String literals in the source code have the Perl default encoding. This may differ.

Comment: If the file came from a mainframe, it was probably originally encoded in EBDIC, and some part of the file transfer process converted that to ASCII. 0x1D in EBCDIC is "group separator", which the conversion process may have converted to 0xa6.

Comment: Re "*ASCII for vertical broken bar to be 166.*", ASCII only goes up to 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive an input file from an unknown source, the most important thing to need to know about it is "what character encoding does it use?" Without that information, any processing that you do on the file is based on guesswork.

The problem isn't helped by people who talk about "extended ASCII" as though it's a meaningful term. ASCII only contains 128 characters. There are many definitions of what the next 128 character codes represent, and many of them are contradictory.

It seems that you have a solution to your problem. Splitting on '¦' (copied from Notepad++) does what you want. So I suggest you do that. If you want to use the actual character code, then you can convert 116 to hexadecimal (0xA6) and use that:

```
split /\xA6/, ... ;
```

Comment: Guess I was not clea. my @c = split(/¦/, 'A¦B¦C'); this works because the string A¦B¦C is done by hand by copying characters from notepad++. If I replace A¦B¦C with $lines[0], no luck. But as you already suggested, I will reach out to the source team asking for the encoding they have used.

Comment: Tried and the splitting of string based on \xA6 works like a charm. Thanks. I must admit, I need to go and read docs to better understand the core concepts like encoding, ascii, extended ascii....etc.. all are so evasive to me.

Comment: @Soumya, You shouldn't have to worry about that. If you always encode and decode as you should, you don't have to worry about that

Answer (score 2):

You should always decode your inputs and encode your outputs.

```
my $acp;
BEGIN {
   require Win32;
   $acp = "cp".Win32::GetACP();
}

use open ':std', ":encoding($acp)";
```

Now, `@lines` will contain strings of Unicode Code Points. As such, you can now use the following:

```
use utf8;  # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
my @b = split(/¦/, $lines[0]);
```

Alternatively, every one of the following will also work now:

```
my @b = split(/\N{BROKEN BAR}/, $lines[0]);
my @b = split(/\N{U+00A6}/, $lines[0]);
my @b = split(/\x{A6}/, $lines[0]);
my @b = split(/\xA6/, $lines[0]);
```